# Getting invalid Authtoken for gmail login?

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, auth-token

In my android application I have created a gmail login.The user can login with the `gmail` credentials already in the phone.The problem is that I am not getting a valid token in android `Gingerbread` os.But in the case of `ICS` and `Jelly Bean`, I am getting the correct token.
I have tested this in about 5 devices.

For checking the validity of the token I used this [link](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/tokeninfo?access_token=YOURTOKEN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved it.The problem is that the token is not getting updated.
So for that when ever accessing a token using getAuthtoken

```
    String authToken=accountManager.getAuthToken(account, SCOPE, false,
                new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
```

the authToken should be validated using

```
accountManager.invalidateAuthToken("com.google",
                    bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
```

Then again after this you should call

> String authTokenNew=accountManager.getAuthToken(account, SCOPE, false,
>                     new OnTokenAcquired(), null);

This will be a valied token.
You can check the validity of the token from this [LINK](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/tokeninfo?access_token=)